# Renoise and dssi and jack

Tags: sound, jack

This may be a little complicated, but, is jack a necessity? I mean, i use renoise, and, since i dont have the need for low latencies, do i really need to use it?

My basic setup ( or workflow ) is that i use csound to render stuff to wav, then import it as a sample in renoise. That goes with field recordings, my own samples, etc. So, i dont need ultra low latencies, and i dont need to patch "cords", but i want to use dssi plugins, and dssi-vst. What would be something of a minimum requirements of apps that should work.

Can renoise load dssi-vst plugins by itself or do i need to use jack to patch thru or something third, i tried to read lot of articles but i got lost in the different setups...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't think that it does particularly *need* JACK (LMMS can work fine with just ALSA until you add MIDI input) but using audio programs without it can be a real pain in the arse. Having your audio come through the painful latencies that Pulseaudio gives it can delay your sound for as much as three seconds. And there are programs that do that because they use the regular ALSA/PA soundserver! It can be a pain to maintain and manage but once there is better integration with PA/ALSA then it will hopefully become way easier to work with.